# Angular UI-Router Thinks Every URL Is Unmatched And Redirects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my HTML, I have the following two links, but when I click them or try to enter them into the browser, my new ui-router code is redirecting them to the `otherwise` url I have specified.  Why is this?

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/#!/folders/529ece6bf0686d1717000003">Folders</a>
<a href="http://localhost:3000/#!/clients">Clients</a>

//Setting up route
window.app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to "/"
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/asfasfsa");
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
          resolve: { factory: setRoot }
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: "/dashboard",
          templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
          resolve: { factory: checkAuthentication }
        })
        .state('folders-show', {
          url: "/folders/:folderId'",
          templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/folders/view.html',
          resolve: { factory: checkAuthentication }
        })
        .state('clients-list', {
          url: "/clients'",
          templateUrl: 'views/clients/list.html',
          resolve: { factory: checkAuthentication }
        })

});

    // Check if user is logged in
var checkAuthentication = function ($q, $location) {
    if (window.user) {
        console.log(window.user);
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Not logged in...")
        var defered = $q.defer();
        defered.reject();
        $location.path("/");
        return defered.promise;
    }
};

// Set Root URLs
var setRoot = function ($q, $location) {
    if (window.user) {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        defered.reject();
        $location.path("/dashboard");
        return defered.promise;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};


// Setting HTML5 Location Mode
window.app.config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
    }
]);
```

Comment: Is your $locationProvider.hashPrefix set to ! and working correctly? (That is, do the links work with # instead of #! by chance?)

Comment: Yes, it is working correctly.  The problem persists whether with ! and without !.  I have added my hashPrefix code to the bottom of my original post for your review.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ugh, simple typos on the clients and folder URLs!!!  agh!  Thanks for your help anyway Sarah!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, simple typos on the `folder` and `clients` urls were causing the issue.

Foiled by typos again!